# Nabla symbol and underbrace show only black dot

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm using MikTex on Windows 10.

I wanted to write the following equation:

```
\underbrace{\frac{\partial\rho\phi }{\partial t}}+\underbrace{\nabla\cdot 
(\rho u \phi)}-\underbrace{\nabla\cdot (\rho \nabla\phi)}=\underbrace{S}
```

What i am getting is:

[image]

These are the packages I am using:

```
\usepackage{hyph}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Naturwissenschaftliche Bibliographien
\usepackage[square, comma, numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % geändert auf utf8
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{afterpage}% \afterpage{\clearpage} um float-Speicher zurückzusetzten
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Veränderung des Zeilenabstands
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{float,rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below}
\captionsetup{format=hang, labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off, labelfont=bf, textfont=normalfont}
%Fremdsprachen
%------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%Abbildungen
%------------------------
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%
%Formeln und Gleichungen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} %definiert u.a. \minuso als Symbol für Standardbedingungen
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}  
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
%SI-Units
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Can anyone help me out where the problem is?

Best regards,

Gesetzt

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You'll get feedback much more quickly if you provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). For instance, it is not clear which document class you are using.

Comment: May not be related to the problem, but do you actually *need* all those packages? At the very least, you can do without `latexsym` since you are loading `amsymb`, and I don't think there is any benefit to loading `epstopdf` on modern installations. Generally, I think it's best to only load the packages that your document actually uses.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `hyph` and `slashbox` are not on my TeX distribution, I have no problem. But I warn you about `fdsymbol`, which changes *all* math symbols in ways that are incompatible with the main text font.

Comment: I’d recommend `unicode-math` over just about any combination of legacy symbol packages, if you’re allowed to use it. Any modern Opentype math font will have a more complete, visually-consistent set of symbols than is even possible with the legacy math alphabets, and makes scaling and replacing characters much easier. Next-best is `stix`, and potentially `mathalfa`.

Comment: With this package list, you should move `\usepackage{textcomp}` further up, perhaps right after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. The `textcomp` package activates the TS1 encoding, and certain packages, including `inputenc` and some fonts, won’t be able to use TS1 symbols properly unless `textcomp` is loaded first. (If any other packages need to be loaded before `textcomp`, or load it themselves with different options, that’s annoying.) Or you could just use `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies to fdsymbol package. At page 19 of package documentation is stated that nabla symbol and others are missing. 
[image]
[image]
Imho you should try to use another symbol package or [take a look at this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font).
I would also recommend, if there is no other need to choose one of the math fonts stated [here](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html).